# Pandas pivot changing dtype float to object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
      n_trigger      device_name  Collected charge (V s)  accepted
0             0  Speedy Gonzalez            2.913136e-12      True
1             0               #6            5.530943e-12      True
2             1  Speedy Gonzalez            1.530740e-11      True
3             1               #6            4.784455e-11      True
4             2  Speedy Gonzalez            6.736956e-12      True
...         ...              ...                     ...       ...
9507       5552               #6            1.155196e-11      True
9508       5553  Speedy Gonzalez            3.378050e-12      True
9509       5553               #6            9.158863e-12      True
9510       5554  Speedy Gonzalez            3.723929e-12      True
9511       5554               #6            1.401557e-11      True
```

and I also have this function

```py
def resample_measured_data(measured_data_df):
    resampled_df = measured_data_df.pivot(
        index = 'n_trigger',
        columns = 'device_name',
        values = set(measured_data_df.columns) - {'n_trigger','device_name'},
    )
    resampled_df = resampled_df.sample(frac=1, replace=True)
    resampled_df = resampled_df.stack()
    resampled_df = resampled_df.reset_index()
    return resampled_df
```

For some reason the `Collected charge (V s)` column is being changed from `float64` to `object`. I found that `pivot` changes from `int` to `float` which is reasonable to handle `NaN` values. But why is it here changing from `float64` to `object`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you used 2 columns which are of different dtypes as `"values"` in `pivot`.

Let's look at a simple example `df`:

```
   a  b  c      d
0  1  2  1   True
1  2  2  0  False

>>> df.pivot('a','b',['c','d']).dtypes
   b
c  2    object
d  2    object
dtype: object
```

this happens because `c` is dtype int and `d` is dtype bool. Now if we change dtype of `c` into bool and check dtypes:

```
>>> df['c'] = df['c'].astype(bool)
>>> df.pivot('a','b',['c','d']).dtypes
   b
c  2    bool
d  2    bool
dtype: object
```

we get bool as expected. Same happens if we change the dtype of `d` to float or int, we'll get the expected dtypes.

Back to your data, if we change the dtype of `"accepted"` column to numeric and then `pivot`:

```
resampled_df = measured_data_df.assign(accepted=measured_data_df['accepted'].astype(int)).pivot(
        index = 'n_trigger',
        columns = 'device_name',
        values = set(measured_data_df.columns) - {'n_trigger','device_name'},
    )

>>> resampled_df.dtypes

                        device_name    
accepted                #6                 float64
                        Speedy Gonzalez    float64
Collected charge (V s)  #6                 float64
                        Speedy Gonzalez    float64
dtype: object
```

we get the expected dtypes.

Finally, if we fill with 0, the float dtype columns revert back to their original dtype:

```
>>> resampled_df.fillna(0).dtypes

                        device_name    
Collected charge (V s)  #6                 float64
                        Speedy Gonzalez    float64
accepted                #6                  object
                        Speedy Gonzalez     object
dtype: object
```

It turns out, you can directly turn them into dtype float objects as well using `astype(float)`:

```
>>> s = resampled_df['Collected charge (V s)'].astype(float)
>>> s.dtypes

device_name
#6                 float64
Speedy Gonzalez    float64
dtype: object
```