# Divide DataFrame by constant, avoid divide by zero error

Tags: python, pandas

I want to divide 1 by the data I have in a multiindex Dataframe. The df:

```
weekday                             Sunday                  Monday  \
sort                                   pre         twi         pre   
error                                                                
volume_pct                      100.000000  100.000000  100.000000   
op_reject_pct                    14.916398    6.631649   34.932520   
iss_reject_pct                    0.500857    1.482323    1.066847   
scan_tunnel_reject_pct            2.642573    1.017678    3.063707   
mechanical_reject_pct             1.514301    0.704245    3.241657   
...                                    ...         ...         ...   
ss2_divert_out_of_position_pct    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000   
divert_out_of_position_pct        0.000000    0.000000    0.000000   
ss1_sorter_aux_mode_pct           0.000000    0.000000    0.000000   
ss2_sorter_aux_mode_pct           0.000000    0.000000    0.000000   
sorter_aux_mode_pct               0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

The desired output:

```
weekday                           Sunday              Monday            \
sort                                 pre       twi       pre       day   
error                                                                    
volume_pct                      0.010000  0.010000  0.010000  0.010000   
op_reject_pct                   0.067040  0.150792  0.028627  0.270050   
iss_reject_pct                  1.996579  0.674617  0.937341  0.753978   
scan_tunnel_reject_pct          0.378419  0.982629  0.326402  0.958242   
mechanical_reject_pct           0.660371  1.419961  0.308484  1.125707   
...                                  ...       ...       ...       ...   
ss2_divert_out_of_position_pct  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
divert_out_of_position_pct      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
ss1_sorter_aux_mode_pct         0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
ss2_sorter_aux_mode_pct         0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
sorter_aux_mode_pct             0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

I was able to do this previously by looping through the dataframe with conditions, but that method was sloppy. I've moved on to creating the dataframe with a pivot_table and using a lambda aggfunc, but now when I do

```
1 / df
```

I get a divide by zero error. I find this strange because on other dataframes when I divide 1 by the dataframe, the zeros just become inf.

The code I use to create the dataframe now:

```
quantile_df = sort_df[sort_df['volume'] > 10_000].pivot_table(columns=['weekday', 'sort'], aggfunc=lambda agg_col: agg_col.quantile(0.75) if (agg_col.name in pct_col_list) else False)
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

```
quantile_df.to_dict()
```

```
 {('Sunday', 'day'): {'volume_pct': 100.0,
  'op_reject_pct': 1.6004576637208159,
  'iss_reject_pct': 1.527310730881171,
  'scan_tunnel_reject_pct': 0.796247328919511,
  'mechanical_reject_pct': 0.524534867532795,
  'ss1_lane_full_pct': 0.8261020961412955,
  'ss2_lane_full_pct': 0.7743555675795205,
  'lane_full_pct': 1.6004576637208159,
  'ss1_iss_not_on_file_pct': 0.2246308712877399,
  'ss2_iss_not_on_file_pct': 0.21029115434018567,
  'iss_not_on_file_pct': 0.4492617425754798,
  'ss1_iss_alt_not_on_file_pct': 0.28453928999398326,
  'ss2_iss_alt_not_on_file_pct': 0.7266480160551008,
  'iss_alt_not_on_file_pct': 1.011187306049084,
  'ss1_iss_unassigned_dest_pct': 0.0699587964100045,
  'ss2_iss_unassigned_dest_pct': 0.0242117212651838,
  'iss_unassigned_dest_pct': 0.09397535806048057,
  'ss1_iss_unassigned_nlpt_pct': 0.12408088235294117,
  'ss2_iss_unassigned_nlpt_pct': 0.03216911764705882,
  'iss_unassigned_nlpt_pct': 0.15625,
  'ss1_iss_unassigned_trailer_pct': 0.0054657093568593685,
  'ss2_iss_unassigned_trailer_pct': 0.006582079813231612,
  'iss_unassigned_trailer_pct': 0.01204778917009098,
  'ss1_iss_no_response_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_iss_no_response_pct': 0.0,
  'iss_no_response_pct': 0.0,
  'ss1_iss_late_response_pct': 0.018154666724017464,
  'ss2_iss_late_response_pct': 0.0,
  'iss_late_response_pct': 0.018154666724017464,
  'ss1_invalid_asgn_to_plc_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_invalid_asgn_to_plc_pct': 0.0,
  'invalid_asgn_to_plc_pct': 0.0,
  'ss1_invalid_destination_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_invalid_destination_pct': 0.0,
  'invalid_destination_pct': 0.0,
  'ss1_no_read_pct': 0.207046920412215,
  'ss2_no_read_pct': 0.4739718022881655,
  'no_read_pct': 0.6668993943361929,
  'ss1_multi_read_pct': 0.0496559559117417,
  'ss2_multi_read_pct': 0.06703681461420863,
  'multi_read_pct': 0.11562622308233822,
  'ss1_bad_xmit_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_bad_xmit_pct': 0.0,
  'bad_xmit_pct': 0.0,
  'ss1_no_xmit_pct': 0.004530535030391544,
  'ss2_no_xmit_pct': 0.009191176470588236,
  'no_xmit_pct': 0.013721711500979778,
  'ss1_chute_jam_pct': 0.05464408089973896,
  'ss2_chute_jam_pct': 0.07256407966419576,
  'chute_jam_pct': 0.12720816056393475,
  'ss1_chute_chute_disabled_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_chute_disabled_pct': 0.0,
  'ss1_diverter_fault_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_diverter_fault_pct': 0.0,
  'diverter_fault_pct': 0.0,
  'ss1_divert_failed_pct': 0.006795802545587315,
  'ss2_diver_failed_pct': 0.024852889462250918,
  'divert_failed_pct': 0.031648692007838236,
  'ss1_divert_inhibit_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_divert_inhibit_pct': 0.0,
  'divert_inhibit_pct': 0.0,
  'ss1_gap_error_pct': 0.0607939643102932,
  'ss2_gap_error_pct': 0.18956801470588236,
  'gap_error_pct': 0.2503619790161755,
  'ss1_lost_tracking_pct': 0.038323751995579025,
  'ss2_lost_tracking_pct': 0.06425588567890622,
  'lost_tracking_pct': 0.10257963767448525,
  'ss1_sorter_not_at_speed_pct': 0.02068014705882353,
  'ss2_sorter_not_at_speed_pct': 0.006698222738233455,
  'sorter_not_at_speed_pct': 0.027378369797056983,
  'ss1_secondary_no_show_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_secondary_no_show_pct': 0.0,
  'secondary_no_show_pct': 0.0,
  'ss1_divert_out_of_position_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_divert_out_of_position_pct': 0.0,
  'divert_out_of_position_pct': 0.0,
  'ss1_sorter_aux_mode_pct': 0.0,
  'ss2_sorter_aux_mode_pct': 0.0,
  'sorter_aux_mode_pct': 0.0},
```

Comment: could you include the outcome of `quantile_df.to_dict()`?

Comment: Added it just now

Comment: I should also say that quantile_df.dtypes shows all data as being object type. It should be float64. Could this be contributing to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` dtype is the problem. I can reproduce your error when I cast the data you've provided to dtype object. But if you cast it to float, the problem disappears.

If you don't want to change the dtype of the DataFrame, you can `mask` the 0s and element-wise divide 1 by it:

```
out = df.mask(lambda x: x==0, float('inf')).rdiv(1)
```

Then the object dtype is preserved:

```py
>>> out.dtypes
Sunday  day    object
dtype: object
```

But it's probably better if you cast the DataFrame to dtype float; then do the division and `mask`:

```py
out = df.astype(float).rdiv(1).mask(lambda x: x==float('inf'), 0)
```

For both approaches, the output is the same (even if the dtypes are different):

```py
                                Sunday
                                    day
bad_xmit_pct                   0.000000
chute_jam_pct                  7.861131
divert_failed_pct             31.596882
divert_inhibit_pct             0.000000
divert_out_of_position_pct     0.000000
...                                 ...
ss2_no_xmit_pct              108.800000
ss2_secondary_no_show_pct      0.000000
ss2_sorter_aux_mode_pct        0.000000
ss2_sorter_not_at_speed_pct  149.293333
volume_pct                     0.010000

[79 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly! One quick question, do you know why the pivot_table causes the dtype to change to object? They go in as floats for sure.

Comment: @rangeseeker I've seen this before. [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71220325/17521785) and see if it answers your question.